# How can I read the title, text and icon name from a pynotify.Notification?

Tags: python, notifications, pynotify

If I have a pynotify.Notification object like:

```
n = pynotify.Notification('title', 'content', 'icon')
```

How can I read the title (to give 'title'), the text body (to give 'content') and the icon (to give 'icon')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [72]: n = pynotify.Notification('title', 'content', 'icon')

In [73]: n.props.summary
Out[74]: 'title'

In [75]: n.props.body
Out[75]: 'content'

In [76]: n.props.icon_name
Out[77]: 'icon'
```